# how to run command in cmd and wait until finishd before proceeding the next line ?

Tags: perl

I want to have a perl script that installs some softwares and runs some commands, could it be done ? if yes, can I have an example of how it could be done ? 
I know how to run command in cmd using perl script, but it runs all of them in parallel, whitch not good for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you you use backticks or system(); when executing your command. Perl will wait for the command to finish before moving on.

so you could either do

```
system("command");
```

or

```
print `command`;
```

good luck